# Redline textfield by error

Tags: c#, html

In my app, I have a textfield which holds a value. When a user clicks the submit button and an invalid value is entered, an error message will be displayed:

In my model:

```
 [DisplayName("Length")]
    [Range(4, 64, ErrorMessage = "You are using a invalid length")]
    public int Length { get; set; }
```

My view:

```
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Length):

            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Length) (4 - 64 chars)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Length)
```

I also want it so that the textfield is red-lined by an error.

Comment: "Lenght" is spelt wrong?

Comment: It's done by default! what are you asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define the `.input-validation-error` CSS rule:

```
.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #e80c4d;
}
```

This class is automatically added to the corresponding input field by the TextBoxFor helper if there's a validation error.